# android recycler view and rotation

Tags: java, android

im with a problem and i need some help with a recycler view,

So i have this recycler view:
[image]

But when i rotate the device, the recycler never comes back..
The thing is, im calling the async task on the onCreate method, so even if i rotate the device, the onCreate method will be called again, and repopulate the recycler view, but in this case, thats not happening. How can i fix this?

When i rotate the device i get this result:
[image]

This is my activity code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;;

/**
 * Created by IvoMi on 15/01/2016.
 */
public class MainFeed extends AppCompatActivity {

    private getData getData = new getData();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_feed);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvFeed);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainFeed.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        new fetchFeed().execute();

    }



    class fetchFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getData.getPosts("http://**.**.***.***:81/chefeBook/feed.php");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            feedRecyclerAdapter feedRecyclerAdapter = new feedRecyclerAdapter(MainFeed.this, getData.resultList, "http://**.***.***.***:81/chefeBook/feedImages/");
            recyclerView.setAdapter(feedRecyclerAdapter);
        }

    }


}
```

This is my adapter code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IvoMi on 15/01/2016.
 */
public class feedRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<feedRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<FeedPosts> resultFeedPost;
    private LayoutInflater context;
    private String imageFolder;

    /* Constructor */
    public feedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedPosts> resultFeedPost, String imageFolder) {

        this.context = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.resultFeedPost = resultFeedPost;
        this.imageFolder = imageFolder;

    }


    @Override
    public feedRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = context.inflate(R.layout.main_feed_item, null);
        return new ViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(feedRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        FeedPosts feedPosts = resultFeedPost.get(position);

        holder.rvTitle.setText(feedPosts.getTitle());
        holder.rvLikes.setText(feedPosts.getLikes() + " Likes");
        Picasso.with(holder.rvImage.getContext()).load(imageFolder + feedPosts.getImage()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.rvImage);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultFeedPost == null ? 0 : resultFeedPost.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView rvImage;
        TextView rvTitle;
        TextView rvLikes;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rvImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage);
            rvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedTitle);
            rvLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedLikes);

        }

    }


}
```

And this is my class that helps me to store the data inside a list

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by IvoMi on 15/01/2016.
 */
public class getData {

     List<FeedPosts> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FeedPosts feedPosts;

    /* Constructor */
    public getData() {

    }

    public void getPosts(String mUrl) {


        StringBuilder postsResult = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url = new URL(mUrl);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                postsResult.append(line);
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        jsonRead(postsResult.toString());

    }

    public void jsonRead(String postsResults) {

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(postsResults);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                feedPosts = new FeedPosts();
                feedPosts.setTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                feedPosts.setImage(jsonObject1.getString("image"));
                feedPosts.setLikes(jsonObject1.getString("likes"));
                resultList.add(feedPosts);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

This is my json result:(its not related to the question but belogs to it so..)

```
{
   "Posts":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "author":"the guy",
         "title":"Teste",
         "image":"1.jpg",
         "likes":"100"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "author":"asfas",
         "title":"dfsadfsad",
         "image":"2.jpg",
         "likes":"20"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "author":"Ivo",
         "title":"fsdfsdafdsf",
         "image":"3.jpg",
         "likes":"15"
      },
      {
         "id":"4",
         "author":"fsd",
         "title":"fsdafdsf",
         "image":"4.jpg",
         "likes":"5"
      }
   ]
}
```

Im also getting this error, when the onBindViewHolder is called:

```
01-16 20:46:42.243 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/Bind view Holder: Called
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****..chefebook D/ViewGroup: addInArray been called, this = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{2ad8a20 VFED.... .F....ID 0,0-960,502 #7f0d005b app:id/rvFeed}call stack =
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup: java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3564)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3509)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.addView(RecyclerView.java:544)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6314)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6272)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6260)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1385)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15141)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:830)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:646)
01-16 20:46:42.256 4500-4500/****.chefebook D/ViewGroup:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If your layout for portrait and landscape orientation gonna be the same, then can you please simply try by adding this line in your manifest file for your MainFeed Activity.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: That dont work for me, because i have some changes in the landscape layout, in the portrait the image have a specific height value, but in the landscpae it match_parent, but thanks anyway

Comment: well that can be handled, all you have to do is to just calculate the height width dynamically and set the layout params for your imageview accordingly. so basically height for your ImageView will be calculated dynamically as follows. if(screenWidth<screenHeight) return specificHeight; else return screenHeight; But there can be an issue with the first element but you can give that a try if you want.

Comment: Hey thanks, but im trying to find a solution, where i can save the recycler view and show it again on screen rotation